# Making a bootable pendrive for custom kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, boot, bootloader, grub

I read the tutorials to make a mimalistic custom kernel from [here](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/1.-Environment%20setup.html) and am able to boot it up as explained in the tutorial over a virtual machine using GRUB as the boot loader.

I think it would be more fun if I could do the same over bare hardware using a bootable pendrive.

**Q1.** I thought of using the normal procedure of making a bootable linux pendrive, but my kernel isnt really an iso image, its an elf format executable. Will the normal method work if I somehow convert it to iso format ?

**Q2.** Any other ideas / link to some resource how I should proceed ?

**P.S.** : Its absolutely minimal kernel. Just boots up, prints something on console and can handle keyboard events, thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really "convert" a linux kernel to iso format, it needs a boot loader to do all the booting.

If using GRUB is not a requirement, using SYSLINUX (for booting from VFAT) or its sibling ISOLINUX (for booting from isos) are likely a lot easier: http://www.syslinux.org/

From my impression that's what most distributions use for their installer images.